# Hadoop Streaming MapReduce for Flume sink files - FileNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, filenotfoundexception, flume, tmp

I am getting following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /log1/20131025/2013102509_at1.1382659200021.tmp
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:2006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSClient.java:1975)
...
```

while MR job is running. Flume changes file name from `xxx.tmp` to `xxx.`
and the MR task can't find the file (MR is trying to read `xxx.tmp`) and throws the error.

I have no idea on how I can avoid FileNotFoundException.

I'm running MR job via Hadoop streaming (`$hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar...`)

Has it any option for excluding xxx.tmp file?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience and I resolved it by adding to my flume config files
the hdfs sink configurations
`hdfs.inUsePrefix = .

hdfs.inUseSuffix = .temp`

I used the  **"hdfs.inUsePrefix"** value of **"."** in order to hide the file from my Hive query while still streaming.

## Issue

I noticed while running "Select Queries" on hive on external tables which have locations that files were streamed into it,I get encounter such errors as

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hmaster:9000/data/etl/sdp/statistics/ppasinterface/some/path/to/a/partition/some_files.tmp`

Examining the flume log file showed a rename of the some_file.tmp to some.file was the reason for failure.

You can refer to the book "Using Flume By Hari Shreedharan" [Page 177/178 if using epub]
Also checkout http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink

Comment: This is the best answer, it solved my problem! Thanks

Comment: @AndreaRomagnoli Really nice my comment helped you out.Cool.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this is by partitioning, let's say I want to run hadoop queries over data coming from flume, flume will post the data using a timestamp (you can configure the sink with a timestamp interceptor to use the date in the destination directory).

Afterwards, you make sure you don't read the latest partition (the latest day), I personally have a main storage in some complete different place and I aggregate the data sunk in hdfs by flume periodically by reading partitions from the last period.

e.g. flume is putting events on the folder 2013-10-27-01 because that's the data from 1 a.m. and I want to process them hourly. At 2 a.m. I run a hadoop to move this data to the main storage, but just this and I don't read from 2013-10-27-02 which is the folder where flume would be writing now (2 a.m.)

example of flume.conf

```
...
agent.sources.avroSource.interceptors = timestamp
agent.sources.avroSource.interceptors.timestamp.type = org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampInterceptor$Builder
...
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfsSink.hdfs.path = /path/to/target/%y-%m-%d/
...
```

Comment: hmmm. so i should move or copy files(not .tmp file) to another place for MR. right? thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer with example configuration of how you can make flume do this for you